# Treeview: First level node without children

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Using Angular UI Grid Tree View, I want to display a structure like this:

```
[0] Element with children
   [1] Child element
[2] Element without children.
```

What do I put in `$$treeLevel` for row 2? If I don't pass a treeLevel at all, I get:

```
[0] Element with children
   [1] Child element
   [2] Element without children.
```

This is obviously wrong. [2] is now displayed as a child of [0], which is not intended.
However, setting `$$treeLevel` to 0 gets me row no. 2 with a "Plus" symbol for opening children - but there are no children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer is simple:

Set `$$treeLevel` to 0 and set the global grid option `showTreeExpandNoChildren` to `false`. That's it.